# Why are java.util.Base64 and org.apache.commons.ssl.Base64 not compatible with each other?

Tags: java, base64, saml-2.0, apache-commons

Trying to upgrade SAML decoding from using apache commons to using built-in Java 8 class. Fails when using Java's.

Is there a way to get Java's to work like apache's?

Can anyone explain why these are different?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't debugging help. It is a difference between classes. Example code is not needed.

Comment: Then show example input and output from each. That would help us see what you see. You could at least make clear which Apache implementation you are talking about. (There are a couple, and they handle whitespace differently.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in the RFC spec each uses to decode: RFC 4648 vs RFC 2045.

To use 2045 with Java's, call `Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode()`, instead of `Base64.getDecoder().decode()` (which uses 4648).